# get included reply in a recursive relationship in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table named **replies** contains all replies of a topic in a Forum laravel application.

```
**replies Table**
---------------
    reply_id
    content
    topic_id
    reply_by
    embed_reply
    created_at
    updated_at
```

replies can have another reply Herself.for that there is **embed_reply** column that hold **reply_id** of included reply.

Now I want details of included reply would have existed on the parent Reply on fetching.

for that i add this Method to reply Model :

```
public function included_reply ()
        {
            return $this->with('replies', function ($query) {
                $query->where('reply_id',$this->embed_reply);
            });
        }
```

And for fetching replies of a specific Topic, I wrote this :

```
$topic = Topic::whereTopicId($id)
                ->with([
                    'replies' => function ($query) {
                        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                    }
                    , 'replies.included_reply'
                ])
                ->first();
```

all of this return bellow Error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2071:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::replies()
```

and I do not know how to do that.
what is solution?

Comment: If you are executing that query in controller, then you will have to include you model i.e Use ModelName;

Comment: I use all required Models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer in:

[laracasts.com/discuss](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/get-included-reply-in-a-recursive-relationship-in-laravel-5)

This is relationship that I must be added:

```
public function embed()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Reply::class, 'embed_reply');
}
```

and this for fetching that :

```
$reply = Reply::find($reply_id);
$embed = $reply->embed;
```